# Finding the right vlookup/index formula in excel to match weeks and dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have two sheets on excel. Sheet1 consists of data from other sheets so Sheet1 is the main Sheet to look at. I am having trouble finding a vlookup formula that can get the accurate information from Sheet2. On Sheet1, in column A I have item numbers and in row 1 I have dates that alternate weekly (16-Jul, 23-Jul, 30-Jul, 6-Aug, etc.). On Sheet1, for each weekly date and item number I get a numerical amount from Sheet2. Sheet2 has the same exact layout except instead of dates in row 1, there are week numbers ([starting from the example dates above] 29, 30, 31, 32, etc.). The week numbers change daily on Sheet2 so for example today it can be 29,34,45,46,51. Right now I have a large range to account for multiple possible future item numbers and weekly numbers andthe best I have is:

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT($A2,LEN($A2)),'Sheet2'!$A$2:$AZ$8000,COLUMN()-4,0)),"",VLOOKUP(LEFT(Summary!$A2,LEN(Summary!$A2)),'Sheet2'!$A$2:$AZ$8000,COLUMN()-4,0))

but the problem lies with the "COLUMN()-4" as I do not know what this does nor does it capture the correct date because it gets the amount but it assumes that all possible dates on Sheet1 (16-Jul, 23-Jul, 30-Jul, 6-Aug, etc.) have no gaps when on Sheet2 there are because not all week numbers are listed. I cannot list them all on Sheet2, only whatever week number and item number is updated and appears, so there are gaps (whereas Sheet1 has every date and whatever does not appear is just left as a blank cell since it is not relevant). Finding a way to change the formula to match the week number with the date might be a possible solution? Hope this makes sense! The workbook is saved daily with a new date.

[google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mHymCIUrymbVXkvYL9gVGWRYTs3K3hCqDG-1clAqHv0/edit?usp=sharing)

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJCGb.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDppw.png)

Comment: COLUMN() will return the column number of the cell the formula is in. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Instead of IF(ISNA(expression1),"",expression1), try IFERROR(expression1,"") unless you want to see errors that are not NA.

Comment: An image may help explain.

Comment: a) Post a redacted copy of your worksheet to google sheets and create a viewable link you can add to your question through an [edit]. b) [Edit] your question to include enough sample data in a code block that we can duplicate the problem. c) [Edit] your question to include an image (or imgur link to image) of your redacted worksheet. While I find it rude that someone seeking assistance would expect everyone responding to their inquiry to retype the data from an image, apparently others don't mind as much.

Comment: That formula would have to be put in column E to BD. The COLUMN()-4 is taking the numerical column index and subtracting 4 so column E would return the value from column Sheet2!A:A.

Comment: Ok I will try and attach a google sheet link, and I definitely would not expect anyone to copy information from an image. I'll go ahead and update, thanks for the help so far everyone.

Comment: Instead of using a large range that you might outgrow, you could put your data in a named table that you expand and use the name in your formula.

Comment: Ok, I included the google sheet link. As you can see, Sheet1 has dates in order to see most of a full year, while Sheet2 has weeks with gaps just for the data for those weeks.

Comment: Also just added pictures to help as well.

Comment: Just an update: I almost got one formula to work but it did not take into account that the second sheet does not have all of the weeks so it is placing amounts into the first sheet based on the order of dates and weeks (i.e. when the weeks skip from 47 to 51, the master sheet reads that as going from 47 to 48). I'll edit my google sheet to include any possible differences from my actual workbook

Comment: Just wanted to update again on this thread. I think I have found the solution with the formula =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$AZ$8000,MATCH($A3,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8000,0),MATCH(WEEKNUM(B$1),Sheet2!$B$1:$AZ$1,0)),""). I edited the google sheet to show the formula and I will spread it throughout all of my actual workbook and refer to here for any problems, thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't try to use :

1. Use weeknum() for week number of the year. instead of manually setting it. eg Let A1 = the date, `=WEEKNUM(A1)`
2. For checking of empty cell , use iferror() or if() to check/zero-fill to check for blank cell. eg. `=IF(A1="",WEEKNUM(A1),"")`
3. Use index-match instead of vlookup. It may be used to look for match both vertically and horizontally.. ref -> http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/
   eg > Let A2 = a, B2 = b, C2 = c, A3 = 30, B3 = 40, C3 = 50 . using A5 as text(a/b/c) input, `=INDEX(A3:C3,1,MATCH(A5,A2:C2,0))`

eg2 > Let A10 = a, A11 = b, A12 = c, B10 = 30, B11 = 40, B12 = 50 , `=INDEX(B10:B12,MATCH(A5,A10:A12,0))`

Hope that helps. (:

+-------[ Edit ]---------+

Thanks for the shared files & screenshoot. Congratulations on finding the solution `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$AZ$8000,MATCH($A3,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8000,0),MATCH(WEEKNUM(B$1),Sheet2!$B$1:$AZ$1,0)),"")` on your own. It is indeed a very good solution. Keep it up. (:

Comment: Thank you for your response. For (1) I changed the dates in Sheet1 to weeknum() values and for (3) I tried to write a new formula with weeknum() values instead of the original dates. I came up with =INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$W$16,MATCH(Sheet1!$A13,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$16,0),MATCH(Sheet1!G$2,Sheet2!$B$1:$W$1,0)) but I got a combination of dates, 0, item numbers, and #N/A. (2) is a good point but I do not know if it will be enough to have Sheet1 reproduce the data in the correct week numbers.

Comment: You get #N/A from Index() due to : 1. there is no exact match in the source field. 2, the calculated rows/column exceeds the field are defined. | You have to experiment a bit with index-match 1st, it is not the same as vlookup. | Check me if I'm wrong : you try to call an item number from Sheet2, based on the dates/week defined in Sheet1. Right? | If that's the case, just make sure all dates in Sheet2 are entered in date format. And experiment with weeknum() properly. That will be my 1st move.

Comment: ..Then only playing with match()... then index()-match().. and then the "" / iferror() cell check. The last step = combine all the proven steps. God willing you'll get a very good code and understand it. (: | Don't rush, just be _sure_. The confidence comes later. | my syntax summary : match(<value-to-check>,<range-of-the-possible-value-to-check>,<type-0-for-exact-match-only>) , index(<result-range>,<the-row-number-of-the-result>,<the-column-number-of-the-result-defaultValue-is-1>)

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it. I am definitely taking my time and this is a tricky thread because I am trying to actually understand what is happening in the formula. I'll experiment more in the mean time.

Comment: Example: Let A1= 6-Aug,A2= 13-Aug,A3= 20-Aug,A4= 27-Aug,A5= 3-Sep,A6= 10-Sep,A7= 17-Sep,B1=29,B2=34,B3=45,B4=46,B5=51,B6=67&B7=82. The date value are in the "date" format. There are 2 routes from here : [1]to get the item_number from a week number, OR [2]to get a week number from an item_number. | Both are possible, I choose [2]. Enter the item number at D1. we do > index(<range-of-the-date-which-we-will-chg-to-weekNum-later>,match(D1,<range-the-item_number>,0)) ...  Specifically, elsewhere enter :  `=WEEKNUM(INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(D1,B1:B7,0)))`

Comment: Tried it and it's giving me the current week number (i.e. 16-Jul = 29).

Comment: Can you share the some sample data? Like at Sheet2 : A1 = 34 .... Sheet1 .... "Summary Sheet " .... (since we don't have access to your file) a screenshoot link may also helps. (:

Comment: Yes, let me put together attach another google sheet that would be the most accurate to my actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Summary!B2 then fill both right and down.

```
'excel formula
=iferror(hlookup(weeknum(B$1, 2), Sheet2!$B$1:$AZ999, match($A2, Sheet1!$A:$A, 0), false), "")
'google-sheets formula
=iferror(hlookup(weeknum(B$1, 2), Sheet2!$B$1:$AZ, match($A2, Sheet1!$A:$A, 0), false), "")
```

The accuracy of the HLOOKUP will depend on whether your WEEKNUM's match the Excel default for WEEKNUM. I noticed your dates are the Monday starting the week so I've use WEEKNUM(<date>, 2). If your weeknum's are offset from excel defaults (implied by the COLUMN()-4 parameter) then this will have to be adjusted.

[Shared worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BYgdWJrK-fvYGJyBbS8VCUbHR1qtNfM2azY3XwB-ssU/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, I applied your excel formula to my actual workbook, I only see blanks and zeros. If it is due to weeknum() default, I would like to keep it as starting on Monday, so how would I change the default to monday? If this is not the issue, the only possible difference on my actual workbook that could affect the formula would be that on the first column with item numbers, there are labels for groups of each type of item number (which does not matter) so A4 could be labeled "Group 3" and A14 could be labeled "Group 5". I don't know if this would affect MATCH look array.

Comment: But I wanted to include any possible differences between my actual and the example I provided.